# GCP - get url dynamically of cloud run instances

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have some cloud run that make http requests between them, the url is hardcoded in the code, is there a way to resolve the url by the cloud run name or another attribute?

Answer (score 4):

Another possible solution could be using [Method: namespaces.services.get.](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest/v1/namespaces.services/get)

If the service name is known to you, you can make a GET HTTP request in API calls to `https://{endpoint}/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/{name}` where endpoint is one of the [supported endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/rest#rest_endpoints) and name is the name of the Cloud Run service to retrieve. For Cloud Run (fully managed), replace {namespace_id} with the project ID or number. It takes the form namespaces/{namespace}/services/{service}.

Authorization requires the following [IAM](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/) permission on the specified resource name :  `run.services.get`

For example :

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://us-central1-run.googleapis.com/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/your-project/services/your-service| grep url
```

Output :

"url" :"https://cloud-run-xxxxxxxxxx-uc.a.run.app"

Answer (score 1):

There is a gcloud command to do so. You could for instance get the url during your build and save it into an environment variable. The following command will get the complete url:

`gcloud run services describe YOUR_CLOUDRUN_NAME --region=INSTANCE_REGION --platform=managed --format=yaml | grep -m 1 url | awk '{print $NF}'`

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```sh
gcloud run services ${NAME} \
--platform=managed \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(status.address.url)")
```

Comment: there is missing keyword and extra parentheses in the end, this command worked for me: `gcloud run services describe ${NAME} --platform=managed --region=${REGION} --project=${PROJECT} --format="value(status.address.url)"`

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way for now (but Cloud Next 21 is coming, maybe great announcement on that; it's a feature requested by many Alpha tester like me).

However, you can implement a bunch of API calls to achieve that. I wrote [an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/3-solutions-to-mitigate-the-cold-starts-on-cloud-run-8c60f0ae7894) where I use that to get the current Cloud Run service URL. But it could be another service.

It's in Golang. Have a look on it, and let me know if you have issues to translate the calls in your preferred language.